# Unable to make a list of pointers to a custom type

Tags: c++, list, pointers, vector, sfml

So, I have been trying to make a list of pointers to a class I have in my project(GameObject). I have tried to do this using GameObject**, list and vector. However, each one of these creates a lot of errors. Here are the relevant files:

```
Globals.h:
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include "GameObject.h"
#include <vector>

#define TITLE "Belty McBelth"
#define WIDTH 1280
#define HEIGHT 720

extern sf::RenderWindow window;
extern sf::Font font;
extern sf::Event ev;
extern sf::Texture playerTex;
extern sf::Sprite playerSprite;
extern sf::Texture tieTex;
extern sf::Sprite tieSprite;
extern std::vector<GameObject *> ObjectList;

extern sf::Clock deltaClock; //A clock that measures the deltaTime(time 
since last frame) in seconds
extern float deltaTime; //Time since last frame in seconds

int setup();
void CleanUp();
void Exit();
void CenterOrigin(sf::Sprite & t);

GlobalDefinitions.cpp:
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include "GameObject.h"
#include <vector>

std::vector<GameObject*> ObjectList;
sf::RenderWindow window;
sf::Font font;
sf::Event ev;
sf::Texture playerTex;
sf::Sprite playerSprite;
sf::Texture tieTex;
sf::Sprite tieSprite;
sf::Clock deltaClock; //A clock that measures the deltaTime(time since last 
frame) in seconds
float deltaTime; //Time since last frame in seconds

Globals.cpp:
#include "Globals.h"

int setup()
{
    window.create(sf::VideoMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT), "Belty McBelth", 
sf::Style::None);
    if (!font.loadFromFile("../comic.ttf"))return 1;
    if (!playerTex.loadFromFile("../PLAYER.png"))return 1;
    playerSprite = sf::Sprite(playerTex);
    std::cout << "Setup completed without errors \n";
    return 0;
}

void CenterOrigin(sf::Sprite & t)
{
    sf::FloatRect d = t.getLocalBounds();
    t.setOrigin(d.width / 2, d.height / 2);
}

void CleanUp()
{
    for (GameObject* g : ObjectList)delete g;
}

void Exit()
{
    CleanUp();
    window.close();
}

GameObject.h:
#pragma once
#include "Globals.h"

enum ID
{
    player, tie, powerup
};

class GameObject
{
    const char * name;
    const ID id;
    sf::Sprite sprite;
    sf::Vector2f position;

  public:
    GameObject(const char* n, ID i, sf::Sprite spr, sf::Vector2f pos) 
  :name(n), id(i), sprite(spr), position(pos) {}
    virtual void Update();
    virtual void Draw() const;
    virtual void Draw(sf::Shader&)const;
    const char* getName() const;
    const ID getID() const;
    sf::Vector2f getPosition() const;

    void ChangeTexture(sf::Texture&);
    void SetPosition(const sf::Vector2f);
    void Move(float, float);
    void Move(const sf::Vector2f);

    template<typename T> static GameObject* Instantiate(const char* n, ID i, 
sf::Sprite spr, sf::Vector2f pos);
};

template<typename T>
inline GameObject * GameObject::Instantiate(const char* n, ID i, sf::Sprite 
spr, sf::Vector2f pos)
{
    GameObject* obj = new T();
    obj->name = n;
    obj->id = i;
    obj->sprite = spr;
    obj->position = pos;
    ObjectList.push_back(obj);
    return obj;
}

GameObject.cpp:
#include "GameObject.h"

void GameObject::Update()
{
    sprite.setPosition(position);
    Draw();
}

void GameObject::Draw() const
{
    window.draw(sprite);
}

void GameObject::Draw(sf::Shader& s) const
{
    window.draw(sprite, &s);
}

const char * GameObject::getName() const
{
    return name;
}

const ID GameObject::getID() const
{
    return id;
}

sf::Vector2f GameObject::getPosition() const
{
    return position;
}

void GameObject::ChangeTexture(sf::Texture & t)
{
    sprite.setTexture(t);
}

void GameObject::SetPosition(const sf::Vector2f p)
{
    position = p;
}

void GameObject::Move(float xOff, float yOff)
{
    position.x += xOff;
    position.y += yOff;
}

void GameObject::Move(sf::Vector2f v)
{
    position += v;
}
```

Pre build, Visual Studio doesn't recognise any errors, however when I try to build the project, I get a lot of build errors. After reading the microsoft pages for these errors, I am unable to find why these errors are occuring.

[Build Error Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2B20Z.png)

Comment: If you paste code, it's normally preferable to paste a minimal working example, so that people trying to help can focus on the relevant bits

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a circular include dependency between `Globals.h` and `GameObject.h`. I would advise you to only forward declare `GameObject` in `Globals.h` and not include the `GameObject.h`. You can do that because you only use `GameObject` as a pointer.
See more here [circular dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes)

Globals.h

```
//#include "GameObject.h"
externs...
class GameObject;
std::vector<GameObject*> ObjectList;
```

GameObject.h

```
#include "Globals.h"
class GameObject{...};
```

Comment: Yup, that worked